# Unable to route to Message endpoints using SpEL in spring router

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a `message-driven-channel-adapter` which is listening to a jms queue 'inputqueue' to which an application is posting a json message in the below format.

```
{
 "name": "Praveep",
 "action": "Drink",
 "age": "32",
 "userid": "pk",
 "details": [{
    "state": "karnataka",
    "country": "India",
  }]
}
```

Inside my `applicationContext` file I have defined a `router` which based on the action will point the message to the appropriate queue.

```
<int:channel id="processEmpChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="drink">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="eat">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="sleep">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>


<int:router input-channel="processEmpChannel" expression="$.action">
    <int:mapping value="drink" channel="drink" />
    <int:mapping value="eat" channel="eat" />
    <int:mapping value="sleep" channel="sleep" />
</int:router>

<int:service-activator input-channel="drink"
    ref="springExample" method="handleDrink">
    <int:poller ref="poller"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator input-channel="eat"
    ref="springExample" method="handleEat">
    <int:poller ref="poller"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator input-channel="sleep"
    ref="springExample" method="handleSleep">
    <int:poller ref="poller"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>
```

In my Class file I have defined methods for each of the actions inside a public method. When I run the java program, I am getting the below error. Can someone let me know where I am going wrong in the `spel` expression.

```
Property or field '$' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage' - maybe not public?
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON property accessor is [not configured by default](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#spel-property-accessors), add:

```
<int:spel-property-accessors>
    <bean id="jsonPropertyAccessor" class="org.springframework.integration.json.JsonPropertyAccessor"/>
</int:spel-property-accessors>
```

Comment: How to configure JsonPropertyAccessor using Java configuration ?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for that; you can add PAs to the `IntegrationEvaluationContextFactoryBean` (`getPropertyAccessors().put(...)`) but doing that in user code would be too late for many cases where components have already gotten their evaluation context. It would have to be done in a `BeanPostProcessor` that runs early in the application context lifecycle. I will open a JIRA issue but, for now, you might find it easier to `@ImportResource` a small XML snippet into one of your `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. For now, I've used `#JsonPath` as an alternative. Could you provide JIRA url ?